# Volley Request Retry not working as expected

Tags: android, android-volley

I have following `VolleyRequest` but the Retry does not retry the request when there is error, for example, suddenly no network when requesting.

```
Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    }
};

Request myReq = new Request(Request.Method.POST, url, errorListener) {
    @Override
    protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {}

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(Object response) {}

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return null;
    }

};

myReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(Constants.DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,
                    10,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

queue.add(myReq);
```

Is there anything I miss?

Comment: what data are you trying to POST?

Comment: it is not retrying because there is nothing to retry, possibly. did you get server error?

Comment: lol i removed the data code snippet, but actually it should not return null in `getParams()`, so for my case is, I got kind of no network error, but it is not retrying, or it expects me to retry manually?

Comment: i see. i am downvoting because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. kindly edit and i shall take back my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static <T> void request(Context context, final VolleyCallback<T> requestCallback, int requestMethod, String requestUrl, Object postObject, Class<T> classType, boolean isAuthenticated, String tag) {
    GsonRequest<T> request = new GsonRequest<>(
            context,
            requestMethod,
            requestUrl,
            new Gson().toJson(postObject),
            classType,
            isAuthenticated,
            new Response.Listener<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(T response) {
                    onResponseListener(response, requestCallback);
                }
            },
            onErrorListener(context, requestCallback)
    );
    request.setTag(tag);
    VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
}    

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request) {
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(PrjConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, PrjConfig.REQUEST_RETRIES, PrjConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MULTIPLIER));
    request.setShouldCache(false);
    getRequestQueue().add(request);
}
```

Comment: Mind to explain?

Comment: oh you are right my answer is not clear but i think you should use JsonRequest<T> instead of Request